# Why does the last sr5 object not occupy memory with overloaded new operator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-keyword, new-operator

When I run this program `sr1`, `sr2`, `sr3`, `sr4` objects are created and values are assigned to corresponding variables. But in `sr5` object, the `name` remains  blank while the `roll_no` percentage shows the correct value.

When change the value of

```
int MAX = 5;
```

to

```
int MAX = 6;
```

everything works fine.

Here is my code:

```
const int MAX = 5;
const int FREE = 0;
const int OCCUPIED = 1;
int flag = 0;
using namespace std;

void warning()
{
    cout<<"\n------All memory occupied------"<<endl;
    exit(1);
}

class student_rec
{
    private:

        char name[25];
        int roll_no;
        float percentage;

    public:

        student_rec(char *n, int r, float per)
       {
            strcpy(name, n);
            roll_no = r;
            percentage = per;
       }
       student_rec()
       {
       }

       void set_rec(char *n, int r, float per)
       {
            strcpy(name, n);
            roll_no = r;
            percentage = per;
       }

       void show_rec()
       {
            cout<<"\n-------------------\n";
            cout<<"Name= "<<name<<endl;
            cout<<"Roll number= "<<roll_no<<endl;
            cout<<"Percentage= "<<percentage<<endl;
       }

       void *operator new (size_t sz);
       void operator delete (void *d);

};

struct memory_store
{
    student_rec obj;
    int status;
};
memory_store *m = NULL;

void *student_rec::operator new (size_t sz)
{
    int i;

    if(flag == 0)
    {
        m = (memory_store *) malloc(sz * MAX);
        if(m == NULL)
            warning();

        for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
            m[i].status = FREE;

        flag = 1;
        m[0].status = OCCUPIED;
        return &m[0].obj;
    }

    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        {
            if(m[i].status == FREE)
            {
                m[i].status = OCCUPIED;
                return &m[i].obj;
            }
        }
        warning();
    }

}

void student_rec::operator delete (void *d)
{
    if(d == NULL)
        return;

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        if(d == &m[i].obj)
        {
            m[i].status = FREE;
            strcpy(m[i].obj.name, "");
            m[i].obj.roll_no = 0;
            m[i].obj.percentage = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    student_rec *sr1, *sr2, *sr3, *sr4, *sr5, *sr6, *sr7;

    sr1 = new student_rec("sandeep", 21, 78);
    sr1->show_rec();

    sr2 = new student_rec("sachin", 21, 78);
    sr2->show_rec();

    sr3 = new student_rec("sapna", 21, 78);
    sr3->show_rec();

    sr4 = new student_rec("vipin", 21, 78);
    sr4->show_rec();

    sr5 = new student_rec("niraj", 21, 78);
    sr5->show_rec();

    sr6 = new student_rec; // error all memory occupied.
    return 0;
}
```

I run this code on linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible code. It is totally unaware of the C++ object model.  Forget it and start with a good introductory book, that explains the object lifecycle, and how to properly create new objects.

**More explanations about what goes wrong: flaw 1**

The problem is in `student_rec::operator new ()`. This line:

```
    m = (memory_store *) malloc(sz * MAX);
```

let you think that `m` points to some valid array of `memory_store` objects. Unfortunately, the C `malloc()` is used to allocate raw memory.  There are thus no valid objects in that memory. Otherwise said, the objects pointed to by `m` are in an unknown dirty state.

Later, the line

```
       m[i].status = FREE;
```

handles the objects pointed by m  as if they were already valid.  This is undefined behavior.  If you don't allocate objects the C++ way (e.g. `new` instead of `malloc()` ) you would first need to create them with a [placement new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).

Now for your simple object trivial object this will not cause too many damages.  There's yet another flaw.

**Even more explanations about what goes wrong: fatal flaw 2**

There is a second serious problem:  `malloc` only allocates `sz * MAX` bytes.  As the operator is overloaded for `student_rec`, it will be called with `sz` being  `sizeof(student_rec)`.  But your code assumes that it is `sizeof(memory_store)`, so that the allocated memory is at least `sizeof(int)*n` bytes too short !!

This is why increasing MAX (and thus allocating more memory than needed for your 5 objects) seems to work.

**Other remarks**

Using global variables as you did, exposing `m` to the outside world, is very dangerous and error prone. Suppose that in some other functions you'd like to use a local variable `m`, but forget to declare it;  you could corrupt your data structure much faster than you'd expect !  You'd better make it a private static member of `student_rec`.

Forget about fixed char arrays for storing C strings.  If a name would be longer than expected, you'd get another serious problem that is difficult to spot (`strcpy` could result in memory corruption in such case).   If you code in C++, take advantage of `string` in order not to worry about such details :-)

Stylistic remark: why not make `flag` a boolean and use `true` & `false` instead of 0 and 1 ?

Stylistic remark: The `warning()` function has a misleading name:  `warning()` suggests that you issue a warning and continue. Why not giving it a self-documenting name like for example `fatal_error()` or `warning_and_exit()`

Comment: i understand my mistakes. Thanku for your help... Thanku very much.